# snmpwalk can't walk table with "accessible-for-notify" item

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I have a MIB where 3 tables contain as first element items marked as "accessible-for-notify", like:

```
    -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.3979.7.4.3.2.2.1
    awOduChannelTable OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF AwOduChannelEntry
        MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
        STATUS current
        DESCRIPTION
            "Description."
        ::= { awOduChannels 1 }

    -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.3979.7.4.3.2.2.1.1
    awOduChannelEntry OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX AwOduChannelEntry
        MAX-ACCESS accessible-for-notify
        STATUS current
        DESCRIPTION
            "Description."
        INDEX { awTopRadioIndex, awOduIndex, awOduChannelIndex }
        ::= { awOduChannelTable 1 }
```

If I try to query any of the remaining items individually (`snmpget`, `snmpgetnext` or `snmpset`), everything works, but when I try to `snmpwalk` or `snmptable`, I got an error stating "unknown column or not readable".

I tried changing to "not-accessible", but it changed nothing.

Why is net-snmp trying to iterate over "accessible-for-notify" items?
What should I do to fix?

---

EDIT:

In my `init_awOduChannelTable()` function the items were being initialized this way:

```
tblnfo->min_column = 1;
tblnfo->max_column = 5;
```

I changed it to:

```
tblnfo->min_column = 2;
tblnfo->max_column = 5;
```

So now it skips the "accessible-for-notify" column, as suggested by @rbelli.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to start in column 2 instead of column 1. You can change the value `min_column` in the `struct netsnmp_table_registration_info` to value 2. And if you need a more fine adjustment you can change the `netsnmp_column_info *valid_columns;` field and says column per column which is valid.